# Passing a component to redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to build an app with multiple screens. It is possible for each of these screens to have a unique sidebar component associated with them, so I decided to build a generic sidebar HOC and pass the screen based sidebar component to this HOC, but I cannot figure out how to implement this. I thought perhaps I could pass an entire component to the redux store somehow and then the HOC would be able to get that component to render within itself, but I don't think/know if that is even possible (Googling for "passing component to redux store" always returns results for "Passing redux store to components"). I'd appreciate if someone could guide me here, I'm completely lost.. 
Thanks

Comment: You're right redux doesn't store components.  Please add to your question the relevant code you are working with.  You should be able to call your HOC from anywhere that you import it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of working with components: not repeating yourself. You don't need redux for that. If you do something like this :

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <YourViewOrRoutes />
    </>
  )
}
```

Then your Header will be available in all your pages. You can do the same with a `<Sidebar />` component, it could take a children which would be your screens, and so you can place them side by side easily.

Comment: The issue is that the <Sidebar /> element isn't a static component, instead, based on the active page of the app the <Sidebar /> would be dynamically injected with some other component.

Comment: Then why don't you just handle condition in your store ? then display or not your sidebar depending on this condition ? It's not a monster project I think it will be easier to handle